# trying to solve this bug in jquery slider controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow

I've been trying to figure this out for many, many hours. I'm having an issue where the indicators on this jquery slider will stop changing opacity if you click on them after the slideshow has looped.

Furthermore the first indicator doesn't seem to be changing opacity at all when you click on it.

```
function slideSwitch() {

var $active = $('.bannercontainer IMG.active');
var $indicator = $('.bannerindicator.active');

 if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('.bannercontainer IMG:last');

 if ( $indicator.length == 0 ) $indicator = $('.bannerindicator:last');

var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next()
    : $('.bannercontainer img:first');    

var $nexti = $indicator.next().length ? $indicator.next()
    : $('.bannerindicator:first');

$next.addClass('active');

    $nexti.animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function() {
    $nexti.addClass('active');
        }); 

 $active.animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active');
        });

$indicator.animate({opacity: 0.2}, 1000, function() {
        $indicator.removeClass('active');
        });

$next.css({opacity: 0})
     .addClass('active')
     .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function() {
        });

}


var start = setInterval(function() {
slideSwitch();
}, 4000 );



$('.bannerindicator:nth-of-type(1)').click(function (){

var $one = $('.bannercontainer IMG:nth-of-type(1)');
var $onei = $('.bannerindicator:nth-of-type(1)');
var $active = $('.bannercontainer IMG.active');
var $indicator = $('.bannerindicator.active');

if($onei.hasClass('active')) {
} else {

clearInterval(start);

$indicator.animate({opacity: 0.2}, 1000, function() {
         $indicator.removeClass('active');
        });

$active.animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active');
        });

$onei.addClass('active'), 10, function() {
    $onei.animate({opacity: 1}, 1000
    )};

$one.css({opacity: 0})
     .addClass('active')
     .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function() {
        }); 
    }   
});


$('.bannerindicator:nth-of-type(2)').click(function (){

var $two = $('.bannercontainer IMG:nth-of-type(2)');
var $twoi = $('.bannerindicator:nth-of-type(2)');
var $active = $('.bannercontainer IMG.active');
var $indicator = $('.bannerindicator.active');

if($twoi.hasClass('active')) {
} else {

clearInterval(start);

$indicator.animate({opacity: 0.2}, 1000, function() {
         $indicator.removeClass('active');
        });

$active.animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active');
        });

$twoi.addClass('active'), 10, function() {
    $twoi.animate({opacity: 1}, 1000
    )};

$two.css({opacity: 0})
     .addClass('active')
     .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function() {
        }); 
    }   
});


$('.bannerindicator:nth-of-type(3)').click(function (){

var $three = $('.bannercontainer IMG:nth-of-type(3)');
var $threei = $('.bannerindicator:nth-of-type(3)');
var $active = $('.bannercontainer IMG.active');
var $indicator = $('.bannerindicator.active');

if($threei.hasClass('active')) {
} else {

clearInterval(start);

$indicator.animate({opacity: 0.2}, 1000, function() {
         $indicator.removeClass('active');
        });

$active.animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function() {
        $active.removeClass('active');
        });

$threei.addClass('active'), 10, function() {
    $threei.animate({opacity: 1}, 1000
    )}; 

$three.css({opacity: 0})
     .addClass('active')
     .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function() {
        }); 
    }
});
```

I've made a JSFiddle (no images, images work fine anyway):

https://jsfiddle.net/zh1mykzp/

I'd be very appreciative if anyone would take a quick look at this code. I'm still quite a beginner so I'm sure the solution is quite obvious..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you were expecting...

https://jsfiddle.net/DivakarDass/zh1mykzp/4/

Working JSFiddle. Check this out.

```js
function slideSwitch() {

    var $active = $('.bannercontainer IMG.active');
    var $indicator = $('.bannerindicator.active');
    
     if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('.bannercontainer IMG:last');
     
     if ( $indicator.length == 0 ) $indicator = $('.bannerindicator:last');
    
    var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next()
     : $('.bannercontainer img:first');    
  
   var $nexti = $indicator.next().length ? $indicator.next()
    : $('.bannerindicator:first');
    
    $next.addClass('active');
     
        $nexti.animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function() {
     $nexti.addClass('active');
      }); 
            
     $active.animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function() {
      $active.removeClass('active');
      });
    
    $indicator.animate({opacity: 0.2}, 1000, function() {
      $indicator.removeClass('active');
      });
    
    $next.css({opacity: 0})
      .addClass('active')
      .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function() {
      });
      
}


var start = setInterval(function() {
 slideSwitch();
 }, 4000 );
 


$('.bannerindicator:nth-of-type(1)').click(function (){

var $one = $('.bannercontainer IMG:nth-of-type(1)');
var $onei = $('.bannerindicator:nth-of-type(1)');
var $active = $('.bannercontainer IMG.active');
var $indicator = $('.bannerindicator.active');

 if($onei.hasClass('active')) {
 } else {

 clearInterval(start);

 $('.bannerindicator').removeClass('active').css({opacity: 0.2});
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.bannerindicator.active').stop(true,true)
    .animate({opacity: 1}, 500, function() {                 
      });
 $active.animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function() {
      $active.removeClass('active');
      });
      
    $onei.addClass('active'), 10, function() {
     $onei.animate({opacity: 1}, 1000
     )};
    
    $one.css({opacity: 0})
      .addClass('active')
      .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function() {
      }); 
     }
    
});


$('.bannerindicator:nth-of-type(2)').click(function (){    

var $two = $('.bannercontainer IMG:nth-of-type(2)');
var $twoi = $('.bannerindicator:nth-of-type(2)');
var $active = $('.bannercontainer IMG.active');
var $indicator = $('.bannerindicator.active');

 if($twoi.hasClass('active')) {
 } else {

 clearInterval(start);

 $('.bannerindicator').removeClass('active').css({opacity: 0.2});
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.bannerindicator.active').stop(true,true)
    .animate({opacity: 1}, 500, function() {         
      });    
 
 $active.animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function() {
      $active.removeClass('active');
      });
      
    $twoi.addClass('active'), 10, function() {
     $twoi.animate({opacity: 1}, 1000
     )};
    
    $two.css({opacity: 0})
      .addClass('active')
      .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function() {
      }); 
     }    
});


$('.bannerindicator:nth-of-type(3)').click(function (){

var $three = $('.bannercontainer IMG:nth-of-type(3)');
var $threei = $('.bannerindicator:nth-of-type(3)');
var $active = $('.bannercontainer IMG.active');
var $indicator = $('.bannerindicator.active');

 if($threei.hasClass('active')) {
 } else {

 clearInterval(start);

 $('.bannerindicator').removeClass('active').css({opacity: 0.2});
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.bannerindicator.active').stop(true,true)
    .animate({opacity: 1}, 500, function() {        
      });    
 
 $active.animate({opacity: 0}, 1000, function() {
      $active.removeClass('active');
      });
      
    $threei.addClass('active'), 10, function() {
     $threei.animate({opacity: 1}, 1000
     )}; 
    
    $three.css({opacity: 0})
      .addClass('active')
      .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000, function() {
      }); 
     }
});
```

```css
.indicator {

position: relative;
display: block;
margin: auto;
width: 160px;
left: 18px;
top: -25px;
z-index: 11;

}

.bannerindicator {
opacity:0.2;
height: 15px;
width: 15px;
border-radius: 20px;
display: inline-block;
background-color: #424b4d;
opacity: 0.2;
margin-left: 20px;
}

.bannerindicator.active {

opacity: 1;

}

.bannerindicator:hover {

opacity: 0.3;

}

.bannercontainer {

position: relative;
height: 390px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #CACACA;

}


.bannercontainer IMG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:50%;
    margin-left: -480px;
    z-index:8;
    display: none;
}

.bannercontainer IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="bannercontainer">
 <img src="Graphics/promotional/LONE28TH.png" alt="" class="active"/>
 <img src="Graphics/promotional/rustie.png" alt=""/>        
  <img src="Graphics/promotional/yungcover.png" alt=""/>  
</div>
<div class="indicator"><div class="bannerindicator active"></div><div class="bannerindicator"></div><div class="bannerindicator"></div></div>
```

Comment: thank you for the response! This solves my problem. There's a bug in your JSfiddle where if you click in quick succession then multiple indicators light up. I think the problem is that the 'active' class hasn't got enough time to be added and subsequently removed by the second click, but i'll try and work on that. Thanks again! :)

Comment: uh-oh, it also looks like the images are no longer being switched by clicking the indicators :(

Comment: @Yurwix Updated my JSFiddle... try with the new JSFiddle and let me know if the images and animation are switching properly. Working on multiple indicators light up.

Comment: i added some of the code from my JSfiddle and it seems to work, though the multiple indicators light up thing is still happening. thanks for all your help :)

Comment: @Yurwix I have again updated my JSFiddle and code snippet. Take a look. It should work now as you expected.

Comment: @Yurwix If you find the answer helpful, can you please up vote and mark my answer?

Answer (score 0):

In each `.animate`  method use this `.stop(true,true).animate`

This will dequeue any pending and unfinished animation on same element when a new animation is fired. Else all the (new) animations will be queued by jquery and intended synchronisation will be lost.

1. http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup
2. https://css-tricks.com/examples/jQueryStop/

Comment: while helpful, this doesn't solve the problem I have which is that the indicators aren't returning to full opacity when they're clicked on